# Prev | Next pager in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, pagination

I am creating my site in Drupal 7. I need

`<<Prev | Next>>`

paging system for my website. It is required, because I do not want to use drupal pager (its not a requirement). Is there a way to change Drupal pager or do I have to use Drupal 7 API?

If I have to use an API please give me a link or help me to change Drupal 7 paging.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to read the Drupal docs on paging.

Here is a way to just get the Next/Prev links and style them however you want:

Drupal 7: [theme_pager_next](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_next/7) and [theme_pager_previous](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_previous/7)

Comment: i can't understant, what should be in that variable '$variables'. And how can i disable Drupal 7 pagination

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this function in your themes template.php
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7
theme_pager will be renamed as YOURTHEMENAME_pager.
Copy the complete function and rename it and make changes in the function as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple pager, with no first/last link:

```
<?php
function phptemplate_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array()) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;
  $page_prev = $pager_page_array[$element] - 1;
  $page_curr = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  $page_next = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {
    $output = '<div class="previous-next">';
    if ($pager_page_array[$element]!=0) $output.= '<a href="?page='.$page_prev.'" class="previous">Previous</a>';
    $output.= '<div class="previous-next-page">Page '.$page_curr.'/'.$pager_total[$element].'</div>';
    if ($page_curr!=$pager_total[$element]) $output.= '<a href="?page='.$page_next.'" class="next">Next</a>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}
?>
```

You can theme it yourself, nothing fancy there.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to add a class to the buttons, use this:

```
function mytheme_pager_link($variables)
{
    $variables['attributes']['class'] = 'btn';
    return theme_pager_link($variables);
}
```